# Powershell - Pattern Matching

Tags: powershell

I have a requirement wherein the log file has some IP address and it needs to be replaced with hostname referring the database. I am getting output with matches for hostname found in database. I am unable to print the IP address for which hostname not found as it is.Can anyone assist in getting the full output.

IP_Address.txt

```
dhhdhja  sasa 10.1.154.6
sasas   swssss 10.1.154.10
assas 10.1.154.14
10.1.154.34
10.1.154.38
```

Hostname.txt

```
10.1.154.6=>Host1
10.1.154.10=>Host2
10.1.154.14=>Host3
```

Current Output

```
dhhdhja  sasa 10.1.154.6=>Host1
sasas   swssss 10.1.154.10=>Host2
assas 10.1.154.14=>Host3
```

Expected Output

```
dhhdhja  sasa 10.1.154.6=>Host1
sasas   swssss 10.1.154.10=>Host2
assas 10.1.154.14=>Host3
10.1.154.34
10.1.154.38
```

Code

```
$log = "C:\Users\IP_Address.txt"
$DB=@()
$DB = Get-Content C:\Users\Hostname.txt

Get-Content $log | 

    Where-Object {$_ -match '(?<IP>\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})'} | 

    ForEach-Object {

        # Try to resolve the IP
        Try
        {
            $IP = $Matches.IP
            foreach($DBE in $DB)
            {
                if($IP -match $DBE.split("=>")[0])
                {
                    $hostname = $DBE
                    if ($hostname -ne "")
                    {
                        Get-Content $log |
                            Where-Object {$_ -match $IP} |
                            ForEach-Object {
                                $_ -replace $IP, $hostname
                            }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            #$_ -replace $IP, $IP
        }
    }
```

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler I am not sure if the below is the logic which i supposed to try and its still printing only the resolved IP's.Below is the code.

Comment: `$log = "C:\Users\IP_Address.txt"
$DB=@()
$DB = Get-Content C:\Users\Hostname.txt

Get-Content $log | Where-Object {$_ -match '(?<IP>\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})'} | 

ForEach-Object {


foreach($DBE in $DB)

{

if($_ -match $DBE.Split("=>")[0])

    {
    
       Get-Content $log | 

                                         ForEach-Object {

                                                    if($_ -match $IP){$_ -replace $IP, $DBE}

                                               
                                                        }   
    }

}

}`

Comment: Hello Team, I would appreciate if anyone could resolve this issue. I tried everything nothing working for me.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I was able to solve it..
Code:

```
$log = "C:\Users\IP_Address.txt"
$DB=@()
$DB = Get-Content "C:\Users\Hostname.txt"
$file = Get-Content "C:\Users\Hostname.txt"

Get-Content $log | 

Where-Object {$_ -match '(?<IP>\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})'} | 

ForEach-Object {

                 $IP = $Matches.IP
                 $containsWord = $file | %{$_ -match $IP}
                 If($containsWord -contains $true)   


                     {

    # Try to resolve the IP

                              $IP = $Matches.IP
                                  foreach($DBE in $DB)
                                                 {
                                           if($IP -match$DBE.split("=>")[0])
                                                         {
                                                      $hostname = $DBE
                                                      if ($hostname -ne "")
                                                                      {

Get-Content $log |

Where-Object {$_ -match $IP} |

ForEach-Object {

$_ -replace $IP, $hostname

               }
                                                                      }
                                                          }
                                                  }



                      }



                  Else{$_}
                 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$log = "C:\Users\IP_Address.txt"
$DB=@()
$DB = Get-Content C:\Users\Hostname.txt

## Loop through each line in IP_Address.txt to do the replacement, as needed
Get-Content $log | ForEach-Object {

    ## Perform work if we run into a line with an IP
    if ($_ -match '(?<IP>\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})') {
        $DBE = $DB | ? { $_ -like "$($_)*" }

        ## Make sure the entry we get back is a valid IP
        if ($DBE -match '(?<IP>\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})') {
            $_.Replace($_, $DBE)  ## Replace just the IP with the IP/hostname from hostname.txt
        } else {
            $_  ## Else just emit the line as-is which still contains the original IP
        }
    } else {
        $_
    }
}
```

Comment: I am unable to get the expected output.Below is the output after running your code and it has duplicate output and also excluding the other two unresolved IP's from printing in the output.

Comment: 10.1.154.6=>Host1 10.1.154.10=>Host2 10.1.154.14=>Host3
10.1.154.6=>Host1 10.1.154.10=>Host2 10.1.154.14=>Host3
10.1.154.6=>Host1 10.1.154.10=>Host2 10.1.154.14=>Host3
10.1.154.6=>Host1 10.1.154.10=>Host2 10.1.154.14=>Host3
10.1.154.6=>Host1 10.1.154.10=>Host2 10.1.154.14=>Host3

Comment: Hello Team, I would appreciate if anyone could resolve this issue. I tried everything nothing working for me.